# Where can I learn about HEMA shields?

Tags: historic-european, shield

I've spent a some time searching for a manuscript that covers things like fighting with large shields like kite, heaters, tower, etc., but I can't find anything. Where can I learn about HEMA shields?

Comment: I've edited your question to focus it on your example of shields and prevent it from being overly broad. Please take the [tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Are you looking for examples of fighting with *just* a shield?

Comment: yes, any help would be appreciated

Comment: For those of us who are new to the conversation about HEMA, maybe you could explain what wiktenauer is and why it's good for researching questions like the one asked. Apparently, this reference material isn't known to the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Some books discussing Long Shield are *[Codex Wallerstein](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Codex_Wallerstein_(Cod.I.6.4%C2%BA.2))*, *[Die Blume des Kampfes](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Die_Blume_des_Kampfes#Longshield)*, *[Kunste Zu Ritterlicher Were](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Peter_Falkner#Longshield)*, [Paulus Kal's fencing manual](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Paulus_Kal#Longshield), [Paulus Hector Mair's compilation](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Paulus_Hector_Mair#Sword.2C_Speard.2C_and_Longshield) (largely re-illustrations of early fencing manuals), and Hans Talhoffer's [*MS Thott.290.2º*](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Talhoffer_Fechtbuch_(MS_Thott.290.2%C2%BA)) and *[MS XIX.17-3](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Hans_Talhoffer/K%C3%B6nigsegg#Longshield)*.

Those links will bring you to illustrations and translations of the text, but admittedly, a lot of them are from an era where an illustration and a sentence or two was provided. I don't know any of the more modern treatises.

Answer (score 1):

The Bolognese sources (1500s) contain information on fighting with both buckler and larger shields, but more importantly, cape. [Achille Marozzo](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Achille_Marozzo) has large sections on both. Antonio Manciolino mainly deals with buckler. Giovanni dall'Agocchie is a good read too.

Have a look at [wiktenauer](https://www.wiktenauer.com/), several translations can be found for free.